# Refresh markers without refreshing entire Google map (Swift 2.0, Xcode v 7.0.1)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios, unrecognized-selector

I'm building an app that displays the positions of buses on a map using the Google Maps SDK in Swift 2.0. I have an XML file that updates every 10 seconds and displays the lats and longs of all active shuttles. In my code I have marker objects that have fields for the lats, longs, IDs, and names of the buses.

I have placed the code that displays the map centered on the location where I want to show the buses AND the for loop that iterates through all the buses positions to display them on the map as markers in a function called **realoadBuses()**. In this function I also have the line of code that communicates with the XML file.

I use **NSTimer()** to call **realoadBuses()** every 10 seconds so the positions of the buses get updated accordingly.

The following is what my code looks like:

```
// runs reloadBuses() every 10 seconds
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10.0, target: self, selector: "reloadBuses", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func reloadBuses() {

    // displays the map adjusted on Campus
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(37.0000,
        longitude: -122.0600, zoom: 14)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    self.view = mapView

    // XML file
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string:"http://link.to.xml.file.xml"))!)!

    let coord = Coord2()
    parser.delegate = coord
    parser.parse()
    print("coord has a count attribute of \(coord.count)")
    print("coord has \(coord.markers.count) markers")

    // loops through all the lats and lngs of the buses and produces a marker
    // for them on our Google Maps app
    for marker in coord.markers {
        print("marker id=\(marker.id), lat=\(marker.lati), lng=\(marker.lngi), route=\(marker.route)")

        // displays the buses
        let buses = GMSMarker()
        buses.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(marker.lati, marker.lngi)
        buses.title = marker.route
        if buses.title == "UPPER CAMPUS" {
            buses.icon = UIImage(named: "uppercampus")
        } else if buses.title == "LOOP" {
            buses.icon = UIImage(named: "innerloop")
        }
        buses.snippet = marker.id
        buses.map = mapView
    }
}
```

**The problem I'm having is that the map gets refreshed along with the bus markers every time NSTimer() calls reloadBuses().**

I know this happens because I have the code that displays the map inside the reloadBuses() function. I have tried to place that chunk of code somewhere before the call to NSTimer(), but then **mapView** is out of scope which is needed for the last line in the for loop inside of reloadBuses().

I then tried passing mapView into reloadBuses() by doing

```
// displays the map adjusted on Campus
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(37.0000,
longitude: -122.0600, zoom: 14)
let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
self.view = mapView

// runs reloadBuses() every 10 seconds
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10.0, target: self, selector: "reloadBuses(mapView)", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

reloadBuses(map: GMSMapView){
    ...
    for loop {
        ...
        buses.map = map
}
```

and the code would build successfully and the map would display without any markers(buses), but then after about a few seconds the app would crash and I would get this error:

```
**2015-10-28 19:42:05.731 GeoBus[1926:107070] -[GeoBus.ViewController reloadBuses(self.view)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f91784aebc0
2015-10-28 19:42:05.743 GeoBus[1926:107070] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GeoBus.ViewController reloadBuses(mapView)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f91784aebc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010600bf65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107cd9deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010601458d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f61f7a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f61b28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00000001063f1671 __NSFireTimer + 83
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f6c364 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f6bf11 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1089
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f2d8b1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1937
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105f2ce98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    10  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000109e03ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000106828676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    12  GeoBus                              0x0000000103ca7bfd main + 109
    13  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010880292d start + 1
    14  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, the map gets recreated every time you call:

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
self.view = mapView
```

I'd suggest you instead set up the map view in interface builder instead, and just get a binding to it through IB's ability to add outlets to your class.

As to moving markers around, what you need to do is to hang on to the markers in a data structure in your code and move them, instead of attempting to recreate the display on each data refresh from the server.

Comment: How would I move the buses without retrieving the new lats and longs from the XML file that are produced every 10 seconds? I have to parse that XML file every 10 seconds to get the new positions.

Comment: Thank you Brett. Setting up mapView in interface builder worked! Just to note, I didn't have to set up a new data structure. I kept the markers as objects.

Comment: @Brett . I am facing issue google maps icons are flickering,Can u guide me why this happens

Comment: @UmaMadhavi I'd suggest you start a new question with enough information for people to be able to reproduce your issue. Thanks!